# VBA Code to hide cell values using Button

Tags: vba, excel

I am currently using a VBA code that is :

```
Sub PasswordPointage()
       Dim Password As String
       Do Until Password = "123"
             Password = InputBox("plz enter password","Password","")
        If Password = "" Then
                   Exit Sub
        End If
       Loop
       Columns ("A:B").EntieColumn.Hidden = False
End Sub
```

But the Problem is that I can't protect my sheet and make it work since I can't hide/unhide columns on protected sheets

Is there any code to only Hide/Unhide Cell values ?? Or maybe color the values with White and make it black when the button is pressed

Comment: Why cant you hide rows/columns on protected sheets? Even with all restrictions I can do this (also via VBA). What is the problem there? get you any errors?

Answer (score 4):

> But the Problem is that I can't protect my sheet and make it work since I can't hide/unhide columns on protected sheets

You can. The easiest way is to protect the sheet with `UserInterfaceOnly:=True`

```
Sheet1.Protect Password:="abc", UserInterfaceOnly:=True
```

Now you can hide/unhide the columns in a protected sheet

```
Sheet1.Columns(3).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
```

Answer (score 2):

### Masking :

select a column which has the passwords. 
change the format the column to `;;;**`
[image: format column]

passwords will be either shown as `******`, or `empty spaces`(if passwords has only numbers)

### White coloring :

select column which has passwords, change the color of the font to '`white`'(or color in sync with the background of the cell)

#### Don't allow to select the column :

You can make a trick by not allowing the user to select that particular column

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
   If Target.Column = 3 Then Target.Offset(0, -1).Select
End Sub
```

#### What above lines does ?

When ever user selects a cell in `column 3` , then user selection will be changed to `column 2`

### Hide/show columns via buttons

Create two buttons/shapes & assign the macros on click even like below :

```
Sub RoundedRectangle2_Click()

Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("B").Hidden = True

End Sub
```

```
Sub RoundedRectangle1_Click()

Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("B").Hidden = False

End Sub
```

[image: Show and hide columns via button clicks]

Now, if you want to protect the sheet, then `format column` should be enabled. (like [Mrig](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36660706/5832518) explained)

Comment: I want a code that helps me when i press the Hide button the cell values will be hidden and then i have the unhide value that unhides the cell values. I used the code above i posted but cant hide the column on protection

Comment: @G.Rizk, see [the updated answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36659976/5832518) with button click events

Comment: @G.Rizk, As the issue resolved. I suggest you to resolve the question by accepting the answer.

Answer (score 1):

When you select protect sheet, check **Format columns** as shown in the image below.

[image]

Else you can write:

```
Sheet1.Protect Password:="your_password", AllowFormattingColumns:=True
```

Then run your code, hide/unhide should work now.

Comment: I have included a button that hides/unhides a column but when it is asked to enter the password to unhide how can i make the password not to show and show *** instead of letters

Comment: You can't do that with an inputbox. You'd need a userform with a
textbox whose PasswordChar property set to "*".

Comment: How can i protect my sheet that i made a button for to hide/unhide it. I dont want to be able just to right click on sheets and unhide it. How can i do it

Comment: Use: `Sheet1.Protect Password:="mrig", AllowFormattingColumns:=True`. Change the password as required. By protecting sheet this way you'll be able to hide/unhide columns.